# Trouble with Python Tkinter Text Widget Indexing

Tags: python, text, tkinter

I am trying to create a multi column heading within a Text Widget but am having difficulty inserting text on new lines or inserting spaces between text. Here is my desired output:

```
Name
First     Middle     Last
```

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
self.root = Tk()
self.frame = Frame(self.root)
self.frame.pack()
self.db_text = Text(self.frame, width=150)
self.db_text.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.db_text.insert('1.0', 'Name')
self.db_text.insert('2.0', 'First')
self.db_text.insert('2.16', 'Middle')
self.db_text.insert('2.31', 'Last')
```

Here is my current output:

```
NameFirstMiddleLast
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The text widget contains one or more lines of zero or more characters each. Initially it contains one line of zero characters. When you specify an insertion point beyond the end of the text, it will insert at the end of the last line. If you want multiple lines of text, you'll need to insert newline (`"\n"`) characters. If you want text inside a `Text` widget in multiple columns you'll need to insert spaces or tabs. You can manipulate tab-stops with the `tabs` method on your `Text` method. See: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/text.html#text-tabs

You might want to consider other ways of laying out this text. You might find `Label` and `Entry` widgets arranged in a grid layout to be useful.

Comment: Spaces or tabs isn't the only way to add text that is not against he left margin. You could instead set a different left margin for a tag, then apply that tag to a line of text.

Comment: Thanks. I've changed the statement so as not to be over-general.